An inconsistency in centripetal force for a rotating falling rod
I came across a question about a uniform rod $(M, L)$, which is initially held vertically on a floor. It is released, tips over, and it is given that the friction is large enough to ensure no slipping occurs. The question asked about the angular velocity, radial acceleration and normal acting on the rod when it makes an angle of $60^\circ$ with the vertical. I used the Work-Energy theorem to find the angular speed and used that to find centripetal acceleration, which comes out to be $3g/4$. However, at that moment, the component of gravity along the rod is only $mg/2$, and the components of friction and normal to the rod are directed against that of gravity, which should only reduce the centripetal force experienced by the rod. How is it possible for the centripetal force to exceed the component of gravity providing it?

What makes you say that "friction and normal to the rod are directed against that of gravity"?  Static friction will, in general, be whatever it needs to be (and in whichever direction) to balance out other forces and keep the contact point motionless.  Similarly, the normal force could point down (if the rod is on a hinge), or, if it can't do that, the lower end of the rod could rise up off the surface.

There are plenty of substances for which the coefficient of static friction is greater than one, and in some cases, much greater than one. For example, a dragster or race car with somewhat gooey tires on a somewhat sticky race track road. The tires on a dragster or race car are not conventional tires; they wear out quickly. The race tracks on which those vehicles are driven are not conventional roadway surfaces. The result is a coefficient of static friction that is significantly greater than one. Alternatively, the rod could be pinned at one end, in this case the ground contact point, but leaving rotation about the pin point free.
Since it is a given condition of the problem that the rod does not slip, you should simply take this as a given.

I understand the given condition that the rod does not slip, my question is more about the centripetal force. It must be provided by gravity, normal, friction. The component of gravity is not sufficient for the magnitude of centripetal force which we arrived at, and considering the normal and friction, since they cannot "pull" the rod towards the pivot, they cannot contribute to the increase in centripetal force. That is my main dilemma, there should to be a simple mistake/solution to this, but I cannot figure it out

@SaleelKulkarni In physics homework assignments, you should simply take given conditions as givens and go from there. Don't worry if you appear to get seemingly contradictory results. Just assume a spherical cow. (That, by the way, is a standard joke in physics.) Those spherical cows / given conditions are there too help you.

@SaleelKulkarni "The question asked about the angular velocity, radial acceleration and normal acting on the rod". It apparently did not ask about centripetal force. So don't worry about centripetal force.

I mean, the centripetal force is just the radial acceleration times the mass, so it is definitely relevant. Ignoring the apparent contradiction, I arrived at the correct answers for the 3 terms, and all the solutions I checked online did the same, but it still feels very weird to me to have a contradiction, because it usually indicates that the approach is incorrect, or there is something that isn't accounted for. How can anyone know whether a contradiction is due to the nature of the question or due to a mistake in solving it.

Well you can never be absolutely sure.  But you can do a few checks as mentioned in the other set of comments.  Another check you can make is to use software like MATLAB to solve the ODE vs time.  How do you check that result?  Well one way is to calculate KE and PE and confirm that KE + PE = const, to numerical accuracy.   Lastly you can use a commercial CAD simulation package to do the same analysis.  If the results all agree then it's pretty safe to conclude that you have the correct solution.  It's overkill for a homework problem, maybe, but it's what I do when I want to be certain.

Not sure how to provide the answer you are looking for.
"I used the Work-Energy theorem to find the angular speed and used that to find centripetal acceleration, which comes out to be 3g/4."
-> I agree with your result.
"However, at that moment, the component of gravity along the rod is only mg/2 ..."
-> True, but the component of normal force $N$ along the rod is also $N/2$.
"... the components of friction and normal to the rod are directed against that of gravity ..."
-> That may be true but it may not be true, depending on conditions (also see my comment below).  It is a little weird to say that $f$ is "sticky enough" for no-slip, but it's a given.  You can almost treat the connection like a hinge in that case, as long as the normal force is non-negative.
" which should only reduce the centripetal force experienced by the rod"
-> Dynamics problems aren't always intuitive because they have additional complications from accelerations.  Your wording makes me want to paraphrase Yoda from Star Wars.  'There is no SHOULD.  There are only mechanics equations to be solved.'  One way to check if your solution is OK is to do things like this.  Set the angle $\theta$ and derivatives $\dot\theta$ and $\ddot\theta$ to $0$.  Do your equations reduce to $f=0$ and $N = mg$?  OK Good.  Now try setting $g=0$ and $\dot\theta > 0$.  You should find that $N = -\frac{1}{2}mL\dot\theta^2$ (which isn't possible unless you have a hinge.)  Now set $\dot\theta$ = $0$ and let $\ddot \theta$ be nonzero. Do things make more sense?  Feel the force within you.  If you check and trust your equations, let them be your guide.
ADDENDUM
I made a quick MATLAB simulation using ode45.  Here is a plot of the normal and friction forces vs angle for parameters shown.   Note that the friction force changes sign and the normal force is approaching zero for the condition you are interested in ($\theta = \pi/3$). If the normal force becomes negative, then the rod loses contact with the surface unless there is some pin or hinge to hold it in place.


Maybe my wording was a bit confusing, my problem is that I am unable to understand how the centripetal force's magnitude can be 3mg/4. Gravity cannot account for it alone, so the rest must be provided by normal and/or friction. But the free body diagram suggests otherwise. The friction has to act "forwards" (in the direction the rod is falling) while the normal should just act upwards on the rod. Even in the case that a component of normal acts backwards, it should still be overpowered by the friction, as the overall force in horizontal direction has to be in the direction the rod is falling.

Everything depends on the relative magnitudes of $\theta$ and $\dot{\theta}$ which tell you if centripetal or tangential acceleration is dominant.  These in turn depend on the value of the constants $m, L, g$.  The friction force $f$ is unbounded, you can think of the joint as more like a slot or U-shaped connection than friction.  As $\dot\theta$ gets large, $f$ can switch signs and point in the direction opposite the rod.  If you plug in some numbers, for example, $m=1, g=10, L=2$ you can make a plot vs time and see for yourself.

Whenever you have some doubts, if not always, it's better to rely on principles and equations.
Let's solve the dynamical equations of this 2D problem. Assuming that friction is high enough, there's only one degree of freedom: let's choose the angle between the vertical direction passing through the contact point $P$ and the rod, so that the position of the center of mass $G$ of the rod can be written as
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{r}_G & = \hat{\mathbf{x}}\frac{L}{2} \sin \alpha + \hat{\mathbf{y}} \frac{L}{2} \cos \alpha = \frac{L}{2} \hat{\mathbf{r}} \\
\mathbf{v}_G & = \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{r}_G = \dots = \frac{L}{2} \dot{\alpha} \, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\end{aligned}$$
using both Cartesian and polar coordinates. The radial unit-vector is not constant: its derivative reads
$$\dot{\hat{\mathbf{r}}} = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \hat{\mathbf{r}} = \dot{\alpha} \, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\ ,$$
being $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \dot{\alpha} \hat{\mathbf{z}}$ the angular velocity of the rigid body.
Now, it's possible to write three scalar dynamical equations to solve for $\alpha(t)$ and the normal and parallel components of the reaction in $P$, coming from the momentum and angular momentum balance equations
$$\dot{\mathbf{Q}} = \mathbf{R}^{ext} \qquad , \qquad \dot{\boldsymbol{\Gamma}}_P = \mathbf{M}_P^{ext} \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{Q} = m \mathbf{v}_G$, $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_P = m (G-P) \times \mathbf{Q} + \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_G$ the momentum and angular momentum of the system, and $\mathbf{R}^{ext} = -m g \hat{\mathbf{y}} + N \hat{\mathbf{y}} + T \hat{\mathbf{x}}$, so that:

x-component of momentum dynamical equation
$$m\frac{L}{2} (-\dot\alpha^2 \sin \alpha + \ddot\alpha \cos\alpha) = T$$

y-component of momentum dynamical equation
$$m\frac{L}{2} (-\dot\alpha^2 \cos \alpha - \ddot\alpha \sin\alpha) = -m g + N$$

z-component of angular momentum dynamical equation
$$\underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{12} m L^2 + \frac{1}{4} m L^2 \right)}_{\frac{1}{3} m L^2} \ddot \alpha = m g \frac{L}{2} \sin \alpha$$
Even if this last equation has no closed-form solution, we can multiply by $\dot \alpha$ and integrate in time to get conservation of mechanical energy,
$$0 = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{1}{3} m L^2 \dot \alpha^2 + m g \dfrac{L}{2} \cos \alpha \right) = \dfrac{d}{dt} E^{mech} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad E^{mech} = \frac{m g L}{2} = \text{const} \ .$$
Now, knowing initial condition $\alpha_0 = 0$, $\dot\alpha_0 \approx 0$ (to move from the unstable equilibrium), and the angle $\alpha_1$, it's possible to evaluate

$\dot \alpha_1$ from the conservation of mechanical energy
$$\dot \alpha_1 = \sqrt{\frac{6}{m L^2} \left( E^{mech} - m g \frac{L}{2} \cos \alpha_1 \right)}$$

$\ddot \alpha_1$ from the $z$-component of the angular momentum
$$\ddot \alpha_1 = \frac{3}{2} \frac{g}{L} \sin \alpha_1 \ .$$


and then the components of the reaction at ground from the components of the momentum dynamical equation

tangential component
$$\begin{aligned} T_1 & = \frac{m L}{2} (-\dot\alpha_1^2 \sin \alpha_1 + \ddot \alpha_1 \cos \alpha_1) = \\
       & = \dots \end{aligned}$$

normal component
$$\begin{aligned} N_1 & = \frac{m L}{2} (-\dot\alpha_1^2 \cos \alpha_1 - \ddot \alpha_1 \sin \alpha_1) + mg = \\
       & = \dots \end{aligned}$$




I'll leave you some algebra to you here, along with the checks about contact $N > 0$ and static friction $|T| < \mu^s N$ is required, and the projection of vector components along the desired/required directions.
